# Can't merge YAMLs with comments

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xml, yaml

I'm doing a tool to automate some work and I need to merge some configuration YAMLs in just one, but I need comments because I need to describe the fields to the future.
I already managed to do this without the comments, converting the YAML to JSON, merging and converting to YAML again. I'm willing to use XML or something else, since I can run it in locally. Anyone know anything that can help me?

Like this:

**File 1**

```
project:
    general:
        environment: ?

    databases:
        # Main Database
        db1:
            host: localhost
            username: root
            password: root123
            dbname: project
            logFile: ?
```

**File 2:**

```
project:
    general:
        environment: local

    databases:
        db1:
            # New Log File
            logFile: project.log
```

**Would result in this:**

```
project:
    general:
        environment: local

    databases:
        # Main Database
        db1:
            host: localhost
            username: root
            password: root123
            dbname: project
            # New Log File
            logFile: project.log
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the kinds of structure you need to merge, and what the output should look like? Because I'm assuming you mean something more complex than placing the items from one after the other. An example of your current code using JSON might also be helpful.

Comment: Edited the thread with an example.

Comment: @PauloNeves it is not necessary to put 'EDIT:' in your post. We have edit history for that, so you can just update a post with additional relevant information, and keep it a single coherent whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @flyx indicated you should look at the round-trip capabilities of  [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (disclaimer: I am the author of that package), even though there is no built-in recursive merge and there are a few caveats.

First of all you should quote your `?` values as otherwise you'll get a warning that mapping keys are not allowed (as a plain `?` normally introduces an explicitly defined mapping key).

Also important to know is that association of comments in `ruamel.yaml` tends to be with the last parsed node before the comment. So in your `file2.yaml` the `# New Log File` comment is associated with the preceding key `db1` and not with the following `logFile`.

If you are willing to make the input `file1.yaml` like this:

```
project:
    general:
        environment: '?'

    databases:
        # Main Database
        db1:
            host: localhost
            username: root
            password: root123
            dbname: project
            logFile: '?'
```

and `file2.yaml` like:

```
project:
    general:
        environment: local

    databases:
        db1:
            logFile: project.log   # New Log File
```

then this program:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml


def update(d, n):
    if isinstance(n, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):
        for k in n:
            d[k] = update(d[k], n[k]) if k in d else n[k]
            if k in n.ca._items and n.ca._items[k][2] and \
               n.ca._items[k][2].value.strip():
                d.ca._items[k] = n.ca._items[k]  # copy non-empty comment
    else:
        d = n
    return d

data1 = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(Path('file1.yaml').read_text())
update(data1, ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(Path('file2.yaml').read_text()))
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data1, sys.stdout)
```

is enough to give you the following output:

```
project:
  general:
    environment: local

  databases:
        # Main Database
    db1:
      host: localhost
      username: root
      password: root123
      dbname: project
      logFile: project.log         # New Log File
```

Please note that it is not necessary for `logFile: '?'` to be in `file1.txt`, as missing keys will be added at the end of the mapping.

If moving the `# New Log File` to the spot after the key is not acceptable, then you'll have to pre-process the loaded data from `file2.yaml`, that is not that difficult in this situation. Doing that based e.g. depending on the indentation in your original `file2.yaml` is possible, but would require quite a few more lines of code to get right and is a bit fragile:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

INDENT=4

def update(d, n):
    if isinstance(n, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):
        for k in n:
            d[k] = update(d[k], n[k]) if k in d else n[k]
            if k in n.ca._items and \
               ((n.ca._items[k][2] and n.ca._items[k][2].value.strip()) or \
                n.ca._items[k][1]):
                d.ca._items[k] = n.ca._items[k]  # copy non-empty comment
    else:
        d = n
    return d


def move_comment(d, depth=0):
    # recursively adjust comment
    if isinstance(d, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):
        for k in d:
            if isinstance(d[k], ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap):
                if hasattr(d, 'ca'):
                    comment = d.ca.items.get(k)
                    if comment and comment[3] is not None:
                        # add to first key of the mapping that is the value
                        for k1 in d[k]:
                            d[k].yaml_set_comment_before_after_key(
                                k1,
                                before=comment[3][0].value.lstrip('#').strip(),
                                indent=INDENT*(depth+1))
                            break
            move_comment(d[k], depth+1)
    return d

data1 = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(Path('file1.yaml').read_text())
update(data1, move_comment(ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(Path('file2.yaml').read_text())))
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data1, sys.stdout, indent=INDENT)
```

The above gives *exactly* the output that you asked for with the corrected (`'?'`) `file1.yaml` and your original `file2.yaml`.

Comment: The `ramuel.yaml` give me one idea, to create a Object in with the comments, extending one of the existing NodeJS libraries to convert YAMLs. If it doesn't work, will will use this calling a py script.
Many thanks for your help and the work done in that project!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with normal YAML implementations because YAML defines that comments are a presentation detail and must not convey content information. Thus, as soon as you parse YAML, you will automatically lose comment information.

There is [ruamel](http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which provides `ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load()`. This gives you a `CommentedMap` (if your YAML has a mapping as root type) which preserves all comments. You can merge such maps element-wise and then output them as YAML again.

Depending on the layout of your YAMLs, you may also be able to succeed in merging them on a textual basis. For examples, for two YAML files like this:

first.yaml:

```
foo: bar
spam: egg
```

second:yaml:

```
sausage: spam
baked: beans
```

You can merge them like this by simply adding indentation to each line and concatenating them:

```
first:
  foo: bar
  spam: egg
second:
  sausage: spam
  baked: beans
```

You'd just iterate over the lines and prepend the indentation. This will work for any well-formed input YAML files **as long as they don't have explicit directive or document end markers in them** (`---` or `...`).

If you want to merge the YAML files on the same level, you can still try and concatenate them, this works fine with my example:

```
foo: bar
spam: egg
sausage: spam
baked: beans
```

You can also concatenate them using into a YAML file with multiple documents, although I am not sure whether this is what you want:

```
foo: bar
spam: egg
...
---
sausage: spam
baked: beans
```

This is guaranteed to work as per YAML specification.

Comment: Will give a watch on ramuel. 
My main problem is that I'm working on a existing project so I can't made a lot of things and this YAML is like a complex Object with lots of Objects inside.
You can see my Edit in the thread with a little example, because the files that I'm using are bigger.

Comment: @flyx actually ruamel.yaml will give you a tree of `CommentedMap`s and `CommentedSeq`s and association of the comments is not necessarily with the top-level one of these structures. So if you have mappings with key-value pairs that have EOL comments, and those mappings are items in a sequence and rearrange those mappings, your comments automatically show up at the new key-value location.